# Update and redraw a dynamic chart using a time series

Tags: jquery, dynamic, highcharts

I have to create an animated bar chart, cycling through a data series automatically but just can't get it to work, using the following code:.

```
$(function () {
    // Age categories
    var categories = ['0-4', '5-9', '10-14', '15-19',
        '20-24', '25-29', '30-34', '35-39', '40-44',
        '45-49', '50-54', '55-59', '60-64', '65-69',
        '70-74', '75-79', '80-84', '85-89', '90-94',
        '95-99', '100 + '];
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#container').highcharts({
            chart: {
                type: 'bar'
            },
            title: {
                text: 'Range'
            },
            subtitle: {
                text: 'alias</a>'
            },
            xAxis: [{
                categories: categories,
                reversed: false,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }, { // mirror axis on right side
                opposite: true,
                reversed: false,
                categories: categories,
                linkedTo: 0,
                labels: {
                    step: 1
                }
            }],
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                },
                labels: {
                    formatter: function () {
                        return Math.abs(this.value) + '%';
                    }
                }
            },

            plotOptions: {
                series: {
                    stacking: 'normal'
                }
            },

            tooltip: {
                formatter: function () {
                    return '<b>' + this.series.name + ', age ' + this.point.category + '</b><br/>' +
                        'Population: ' + Highcharts.numberFormat(Math.abs(this.point.y), 0);
                }
            },

            series: [{
                name: 'Male',
                data: [-2.2, -2.2, -2.3, -2.5, -2.7, -3.1, -3.2,
                       -3.0, -3.2, -4.3, -4.4, -3.6, -3.1, -2.4,
                       -2.5, -2.3, -1.2, -0.6, -0.2, -0.0, -0.0]
            }, {
                name: 'Female',
                data: [2.1, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.6, 3.0, 3.1, 2.9,
                       3.1, 4.1, 4.3, 3.6, 3.4, 2.6, 2.9, 2.9,
                       1.8, 1.2, 0.6, 0.1, 0.0]
            }]
        });
    });
});
```

How can I get it to update the series and redraw the chart ?

Comment: do you want to update/redraw chart whenever you get updated response from a server call/ajax/API?

Comment: Could you elaborate your question, cause is a little bit unclear. Let us know what is your goal